# Implementing `.ItemsSource` methode in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple ListBox in WPF XAML, to which I assign the items from a list called `tour` with the following one line code in C#:

```
listBoxDutyDays.ItemsSource = tour;
```

I would like to do exact the same thing but in XAML.

Thats how it looks like:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxDutyDays">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Day}"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Date}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

How would the code in XAML look like?

I have tried this accordingly:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxDutyDays">
        <ListBox.DataContext>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding tour}"/>
        </ListBox.DataContext>
```

but it didn't work...

Comment: Bind it to a property in the view's DataContext: `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tour}">`.

Comment: As a note, for displaying text you could use a (simpler) TextBlock, not a Label: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}"/>`

Comment: A ListBox in the DataContext of a ListBox? That makes no sense. There should be an object, i.e. an instance of a class with a public `Tour` property. Assign that object to the DataContext of the Window. If you search StackOverflow for e.g. "WPF DataContext", you'll find an abundance of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxDutyDays" ItemsSource="{Binding tour}">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Day}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Date}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it with `<ListBox x:Name="listBoxDutyDays" ItemsSource="{Binding tour}">`but it doesn't work. I think I still have to put in the DataContext somewhere and somehow, but how?

Comment: @MarcelFuchs: How is `tour` defined?

Comment: tour is the itemssource name of their source code..you want to bind your itemssource name..Hope this helpful

Comment: @mm8 Sorry, for the late reply. That's how tour is defined:    `for (int i = 1; i<=6; i++)
            {
                tour.Add(new DutyDay() { Day = "Day " + i + ":" });
            }`

Comment: @MarcelFuchs: No, i mean the actual property. How is it defined? Please edit your question and include the class where `tour` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add an explanation to 'Bhuvanesh Jay' answer.

You will need 2 things in order to make it work:

1. Class with `Tour` property.
   Such as:

   ```
   private ObservableCollection<DutyDay> tour;

   public ObservableCollection<DutyDay> Tour
   {
       get
       {
           return tour;
       }
       set
       {
           tour = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Tour));
       };
   }
   ```
2. Set that class as the `DataContext` of the `ListBox` (Or any control up in the hierarchy of the ListBox)

Then change your code to:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxDutyDays" ItemsSource="{Binding tour}">
```

What you tried to do in Xaml, doesn't make sense. You write:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxDutyDays">
    <ListBox.DataContext>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding tour}"/>
    </ListBox.DataContext>
```

That in code is the same like:

```
listBox.DataContext = new ListBox() 
{ 
    ItemsSource = \* Binding to tour *\
}
```